# Enviar texto a una ventana (Python)

Tags: python, cmd, encriptación, gpg

Tengo que ejecutar un comando cmd desde python y lo hago mediante subprocess:

El comando en cmd seria "gpg -d nombreArchivoEncriptado.gpg", en python seria algo asi:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['gpg' ,'-d', 'nombreArchivoEncriptado.gpg'])
```

En ese momento me sale una ventana para introducir la clave con la que desencriptar el archivo y no se como enviarle texto a dicha ventana, gpg no tiene un comando en plan "-password contraseña" que poner como argumento después y estoy sin ideas.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: `gpg -d --batch --passphrase contraseña nombrearchivo.gpg`

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona a la perfección!